# How to filter rows on Max date and Max Id

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL table

```
RecordID      RecordState     Time
-----------------------------------
record1       failed          1:00
record1       passed          2:00

record2       passed          2:15

record3       failed          3:00

record4       passed          4:00
record4       failed          5:00
```

I need to select only 'failed' records.

```
select RecordID, max(RecordState)
from RecordTable a
inner join RecordStateTable b
on a.recordID = b.recordID
group by RecordID
```

This pulls all the fail record but the problem here is **record4** where the value was first passed and then failed so max(recordstate) for this record is passed. I somehow also need to modify it for Max(Time) as well but I cant figure how.

The expected result is `record3(failed),record4(failed)`

Comment: So your results should only contain record 3? or both record 3 and 4?

Comment: Can you add the expected result

Comment: Do you have two tables? You query suggests you have a RecordTable and a RecordStateTable but your question suggests you only have a single table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to return the latest result from each record:

```
    declare @RecordTable TABLE (
        RecordID varchar(10),
        RecordState varchar(10),
        [Time] time
    )

    insert into @RecordTable
    values
        ('record1', 'failed', '1:00'),
        ('record1', 'passed', '2:00'),
        ('record2', 'passed', '2:15'),
        ('record3', 'failed', '3:00'),
        ('record4', 'passed', '4:00'),
        ('record4', 'failed', '5:00')

    select  a.RecordID, a.RecordState, b.[Time]
    from    @RecordTable a
        inner join (
            select  RecordID, max([Time]) as [Time]
            from    @RecordTable
            group by RecordID
        ) b on b.RecordID = a.RecordID and a.[Time] = b.[Time] -- only return the most recent version

    --record4   failed  05:00:00.0000000
    --record3   failed  03:00:00.0000000
    --record2   passed  02:15:00.0000000
    --record1   passed  02:00:00.0000000
```

This gets the `max(Time)` for each record and grabs the status from that row. If you only want failed (or passed) records, just add `where a.RecordState = 'whatever'`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting max state which can lead to very confusing results (since it is just string) - you can select `max(Time)` for each `RecordID` and then take only records having failed state at max time:

```
select T1.*
from
(
    select
        RecordID,
        max(Time) as Time
    from RecordStateTable 
    group by RecordID
) as T
    inner join RecordStateTable as T1 on T1.RecordID = T.RecordID and T1.Time = T.Time
where T1.RecordState = 'failed'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic (window function) to get the max time for each recordID and show only the max record times in a failed status.

```
with CTE AS (
Select RecordID, RecordState, Time, max(time) over (partition by RecordID) mt
FROM table)
Select * from cte where mt = time and recordState = 'failed'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Select * From
(
select *,
       row_number()over(partition by RecordID order by [time] desc) as rn 
from yourtable
) A
Where RN = 1 and RecordState = 'Failed'
```

Use `Row_number` to identify the maximum `time` for each `RecordID` and filter the max time along with `RecordState = 'Failed'`

Answer (score 0):

This will return the latest time with only failed status

```
select RecordID,RecordState row_number
over (partition by recordID
order by Time desc) as rn   from 
yourtable
where RecordState = 'failed' and rn = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid? For sure you're missing some commas and parentheses and even then I don't believe you can access rn in the where clause?

Comment: That actually worked for me/ and for sure yes you can access rn in where

Comment: You've clearly left some things out, you have two closing parentheses and one opening parentheses. Your select isn't valid, and I don't see how rn can exist in that where clause. Perhaps you meant to use an embedded query same as Prdp?

Answer (score 0):

I would use APPLY to do this.

```
SELECT rt.RecordID, ca.RecordState
FROM RecordTable rt
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 RecordState, Time
             FROM RecordTable
             WHERE RecordID = rt.RecordID
             ORDER BY Time DESC) ca
WHERE rt.Time = ca.Time AND ca.RecordState = 'failed'
```

Based on your query, I suspect there are actually two tables. Assuming RecordID is the PK on your RecordTable you can simplify the above to this.

```
SELECT rt.RecordID, ca.RecordState
FROM RecordTable rt
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 RecordState
             FROM RecordStateTable
             WHERE RecordID = rt.RecordID
             ORDER BY Time DESC) ca
WHERE ca.RecordState = 'failed'
```